# Django - If one model field exists, another field must be empty/inaccessible

Tags: django

I have a model called Team.  Team has one User as team_leader and can have multiple team_member's.

Under User, I added the following fields:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    team_leader = models.OneToOneField(Team, null=True, blank=True)
    team_member = models.ForeignKey(Team, null=True, blank=True)
```

Obviously a User shouldn't be a team_leader and team_member at the same time.  I have set both fields as null/blank so I can always just leave one of them blank.  However for extra precaution I'd like to completely disable one of these fields when the other field is activated.

I'm aware of the [disabled](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#disabled) function, but it is only for disabling the field on a form.  I want to eliminate any chance of tampering by completely disabling one model field.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
class UserForm(ModelForm):
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(UserForm, self).clean()
        team_leader = cleaned_data.get('team_leader', None)
        team_member = cleaned_data.get('team_member', None)
        if team_leader and len(team_member)!=0:
             if team_leader in team_member:
                 raise forms.ValidationError("team_leader can't in team_member")

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['team_leader', 'team_member']

class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = UserForm
```